# Bitcode Auto Recompilation

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, app-store-connect, bitcode

we are in the final phase of App Store publishing. We could see new feature that added to iTunes connect that is not exist last year when i have published my last app.

[image]

My question is, If i have not enabled bit code for one of the library used in my app, then i have to enable the checkbox for "Dont use bitcode auto-recompilation" ???

Or simply my app is not bit code enabled, So i need to enable this checkbox???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not necessary, I did not enable bit code in my app also not checked this checkbox.

Now my app is approved by apple and it is in Live !

Answer (score 0):

You should disable bitcode checkbox as its stated in apple doc -

"If you provide bitcode, all apps and frameworks in the app bundle (all targets in the project) need to include bit code."
Here is the link for the same

https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know;
you should not select that checkbox.

Although using bitcode, the ipa file size incerements, the application will be more healty.